# How can I configure Vue-CLI 3 to produce a page without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I have a static page that doesn't need JavaScript. I'm using vue-cli 3 and would like to pass the HTML file through webpack for the purpose of minification. However, this doesn't seem to be possible. Inside `vue.config.js`, I have this:

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    static_page: {
      template: "./public/static_page.html",
      entry: ""
    }
  }
};
```

Of course, this fails because `entry` is required and cannot be empty. Simply placing the file into `public` will cause vue-cli to copy the file into `dist` unchanged. This is OK but it's not minified. So how can I tell vue-cli to process a HTML file without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually invoke the HTML Webpack Plugin. Here's my `vue.config.js`

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: "./public/static_page.html",
                filename: "static_page.html",
                chunks: [],
                minify: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeComments: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true
                }
            })
        ]
    }
};
```

Vue CLI is still copying the file from `public` to `dist` unchanged [as it would with any other static asset](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling). HTML Webpack Plugin is overwriting this file with the minified version.

Also, setting the `minify` option to `true` doesn't seem to do anything. The options have to be listed out explicitly. See [Issue #1094](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1094).

Another useful link is the list of [HTML Webpack Plugin options](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options).